# How to display entire MAC address table on HP switches

Tags: switch, mac-address, hp

I want to display the whole MAC address table without needing to press 'space' for the next page, so that if there are 50 entries in the table I'd be able to view them with a single command.

I'm working on an HP switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either adjust the screen length as Konstantin has suggested (`screen-length disable` isn't available on many switches though) or you can disable paging altogether using

`no page`

Re-enable with `page`.

Comment: Do i use it on privileged exec mode?

Comment: @user19215 At least on Provision series switches `[no] page` works in all modes.

Answer (score 6):

For HP you can use:

in user-view : 
screen-length disable

Then all output will be without "page" interruption.

Comment: @jonathanjo On Cisco IOS devices, you mean. On Cisco ASAs, it's `pager lines 0`

Comment: Just for cross-reference, on Cisco IOS it's `term length 0`

Comment: @jonathanjo Sure. I know this post was about switches but I wanted to make sure people knew about Cisco command differences between models (because can't standardize anything, apparently).